# Accessibility error on bootstrap navbar button

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, accessibility

The hamburger menu on a Boostrap menu is showing up in the Web Accessibility Tool, at wave.webaim.org, as an error: A button is empty or has no value text.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
 <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       </button>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of the `.sr-only` class. Under [Conveying the icon's meaning to assistive technologies](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-validation) (you'll have to scroll down some):

> To ensure that assistive technologies – such as screen readers – correctly convey the meaning of an icon, additional hidden text should be included with the .sr-only class...

```
<div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="icon-bar"></span>
           <span class="sr-only">Toggle Menu</span>
       </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice ... I couldn't see the forest for the trees ... Thanks